In C#, why does System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize fail to serialize correctly when using dependency injection (interfaces)?
Why does the following write out only "{}"?
var myLogin = new TestLogin
{
    UserName = "cr@home.com",
    Password = "Pass123"
};
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(myLogin));
 
public interface ITest;

public class TestLogin : ITest
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("userName")]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("password")]
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("password")]
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}


First point of confusion: why are you calling your serialize methods "Parse"? (Parsing is deserialization.)

It doesn't help that your interface declaration is invalid, so we can't just copy/paste the code to test it... and I'd personally just use a console app instead of a unit test, so we don't need to guess which libraries you're using.

Works in Visual Studio for me.  .NET 8 Jon. I've checked and checked and it works fine.  Interfaces, just like classes can terminate like that. It's an NUnit test, and console apps are a bit outdated for most users, and don't really fit with TDD do they?  Can't exactly put one into CI/CD pipeline

Unlike Json.NET, System.Text.Json only serializes declared properties of some base type or interface (rather than all properties) when serializing some derived instance.  See System.Text.Json serialization not using derived classes and Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?.  To force all properties to be serialized, declare as object: System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(request).  Do those two questions answer yours also?

My mistake - how odd. Will need to check when that was added to C#. Sorry about that! (I stand by things being simpler if you just use a console app though. With top-level statements, it ends up being a simpler minimal example.)

Sorry - must be because I edited my question?

@csharpforevermore - System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<object>(request) is the code example.  Now if you need to deserialize them it's more complicated, but do you?

That's the one. Thanks @dbc!

@csharpforevermore - It works for me, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/bYRFPw

Ah OK our comments crossed.  Do you need an answer, or shall we mark as a duplicate?

I don't see mention of interfaces in the other questions so I don't think it's a duplicate?  One talks about serializing abstract classes, and the other derived.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

"and console apps are a bit outdated for most users, and don't really fit with TDD do they" - Stack Overflow isn't a CI pipeline though. It's a Q&A site, and I think it's really helpful to make it as easy as possible for those who are considering answering your question to reproduce the issue. I personally think that's simplest with a console app. I've answered countless questions by writing (or copying) console apps - I have never once decided "I know, I'll put that question into a CI pipeline." It's about the right tool for the job.

Just as an example, https://gist.github.com/jskeet/dee7375397fad316dafeceb5a51c5c0d demonstrates the problem (and actually points to the fact that the properties declared in the interface are relevant) without needing any third-party libraries. Just dotnet new console, put that code in Program.cs, then dotnet run. But I don't want to sound too hard - the fact that this is mostly complete (basically just missing using directives) and reasonably minimal makes it better than most questions :)

@JonSkeet BTW Parse means "to process" if you look at the meaning of the intransitive verb - not to serialize per se.

@csharpforevermore: In every language I've ever seen, "parse" is used to deserialize from some "wire format", often strings. For example, int.TryParse, XDocument.Parse. You can choose to argue technicalities about "I only mean processing" if you want, but that doesn't make it any less confusing to readers who are used to what it always means in this context. (I'd be surprised if you could find any examples of the term "parse" being used for serialization as opposed to deserialization in a common framework.)
